# UK equivalent of annualcreditreport.com?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-score, credit-report, credit-history

From https://money.stackexchange.com/a/52272 I learned that (apparently) US federal law says I can "Get a free copy of your credit report every 12 months from each credit reporting company.", through the website in the title.

I live in the UK, though. Is there such a thing here?

Answer (score 3):

The three main credit reference agencies now allow free access to at least an abbreviated form of your report. Search for ClearScore (for Equifax), CreditExpert (for Experian) and Noddle (for Callcredit).

Answer (score 1):

If you are a victim of identity theft and/or financially vulnerable, then yes, you can obtain a free copy of your credit report. Otherwise, it is £2 to access each of your reports via mail.

https://www.gov.uk/government/news/credit-reports-available-online-for-all-consumers